# Ho to install new font-family in a Zurb Founation project

Tags: zurb-foundation, font-family, zurb-foundation-5

Can you help me about how to add a new font-family in a Foundation project. This new font-family can be installed locally or external like Google Font Web.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use SASS you can modify `$header-font-family`, `$paragraph-font-family` and `$code-font-family`

Comment: Thank you... but, I want add a new font-family. I know that there are by default the following font-family :   $font-family-sans-serif: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
// $font-family-serif: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
// $font-family-monospace: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Courier, monospace;

Comment: Did you try to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880621/external-font-does-not-work-in-foundation-zurb-css)

Comment: He didn't use SASS method.

Comment: You install a Google Font just like you normally would (import or link method) and then put the family in front of the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your mixin

```
@mixin font-face($style-name, $file, $family, $category:"") {
    $filepath: "fonts/" + $family + "/" + $file;
    @font-face {
        font-family: "#{$style-name}";
        src: url($filepath + ".eot");
        src: url($filepath + ".eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url($filepath + ".woff") format('woff'), url($filepath + ".ttf")  format('truetype'), url($filepath + ".svg#" + $style-name + "") format('svg');
    }
    %#{$style-name} {
        font: {
            @if $category != "" {
                family: "#{$style-name}", #{$category};
            }
            @else {
                family: "#{$style-name}";
                weight: normal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And used it like this

```
@include font-face($style-name, $file, $family, $category);
```

[Answer found quickly on the web](http://clubmate.fi/scss-font-face-mixin/)...

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
     @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=yourFontFamilyName');
</style>
```

Now use this font-family in inline css.
Style tag is removed by some webmail(for example gmail) so you can put it inside body.

If you are going to use foundation architecture then put the above line in foundation.css